# How can I reduce if/else statements Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to reduce these if else statements. How can I proceed ?I'm using function in javascript to filter showing data in devExpress gridView.
I want to put them in many or one function.any one can help me ?

```
function OnSelectClient()
        {
            var clientNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchClient").val();
            var recordNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchDossier").val();
            var StartDateFromFilter = StartDateFrom.GetText();
            var StartDateToFilter = StartDateTo.GetText();
            var ConfirmationDateFromFilter = ConfirmationDateFrom.GetText();
            var ConfirmationDateToFilter = ConfirmationDateTo.GetText();

            if (clientNameFilter != "" && recordNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "")
            {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#) And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }
            else if (clientNameFilter != "" && recordNameFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "')And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }
            else if (clientNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#) And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }

           else if (clientNameFilter != "" && recordNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
               gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
               gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
               gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
           }
            else if (clientNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
            }
            else if (clientNameFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }
            else if (recordNameFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }

            else if (recordNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "')  And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
            }

            else if (ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#) And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
            }

            else if (clientNameFilter != "" && recordNameFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "')");
            }

            else if (clientNameFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", clientNameFilter);
            }
            else if (StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "")
            {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
            }

            else if (ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
            }
            else if (recordNameFilter != "") {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", recordNameFilter);
            }
            else
            {
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
                gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
                gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("");
            } 
        }
```

Comment: If the code is working questions like this are better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do, is determine which variable is affecting on which condition inside your `gvBatchBilling.applyFilter()`.

For example, when `StartDateFromFilter` is not empty string, you are applying `[StartDate] >= #StartDateFromFilter#` condition. Then you need to separate all checks to variable-specific `if` blocks and generate correspond condition only if you need. It's possible to use a trick: you may add all conditions into `conditions` array. And then, if all your variables are empty strings, your `conditions` array will be empty. If it's not empty, you can just `join()` all conditions into a string where all conditions are separated with `And` word.

```
function OnSelectClient() {
    var clientNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchClient").val();
    var recordNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchDossier").val();
    var StartDateFromFilter = StartDateFrom.GetText();
    var StartDateToFilter = StartDateTo.GetText();
    var ConfirmationDateFromFilter = ConfirmationDateFrom.GetText();
    var ConfirmationDateToFilter = ConfirmationDateTo.GetText();

    var conditions = [];

    if (clientNameFilter != '') {
        // No need to generate "[ClientName] = clientNameFilter"
        // because it's exactly what AutoFilterByColumn() does — apply
        // field "equals" filter.
        gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", clientNameFilter);
    }

    if (recordNameFilter != '') {
        // The same as above
        gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", recordNameFilter);
    }

    if (StartDateFromFilter != '') {
        conditions.push("([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)");
    }

    if (StartDateToFilter != '') {
        conditions.push("([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
    }

    if (ConfirmationDateFromFilter != '') {
        conditions.push("([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)");
    }

    if (ConfirmationDateToFilter != '') {
        conditions.push("([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
    }

    if (conditions.length > 0) {
        gvBatchBilling.applyFilter(conditions.join(' And '));
    }
}
```

It will, at least, help you understand what is happening in your code. Because it's becoming simpler.

Comment: Thanks! this what I need :D

Answer (score 0):

Start by nesting some of these conditionals. It will save overhead if you aren't making the same checks over and over. Here's an example:

```
if(clientNameFilter != "") {
        if (recordNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "")
        {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#) And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
        }
        else if (recordNameFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "')And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
        }
        else if (StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#) And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
        }

       else if (recordNameFilter != "" && StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
           gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
           gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
           gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
       }
        else if (StartDateFromFilter != "" && StartDateToFilter != "") {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#)");
        }
        else if (ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "" && ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And ([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)");
        }

        else if (recordNameFilter != "") {
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter("([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "')");
        }
        else{
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
            gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", clientNameFilter);
        }
```

Once you get those cleaned up, you will be able to eliminate some duplicates. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Are there any solution without using many "if" ?

Comment: @dhouhababay Yes. Work on more nesting. This work must be done on your side, we can't help you for that. If your code need that much of conditions, you ***may*** have an issue on the algorithmic side, so you might want to rethink this thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code using *ternary* operators, if you want to reduce the if/else blocks. Your code can be reconstructed as follows.

```
function OnSelectClient()
{
    var clientNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchClient").val();
    var recordNameFilter = $("#idInputSearchDossier").val();
    var StartDateFromFilter = StartDateFrom.GetText();
    var StartDateToFilter = StartDateTo.GetText();
    var ConfirmationDateFromFilter = ConfirmationDateFrom.GetText();
    var ConfirmationDateToFilter = ConfirmationDateTo.GetText();

    gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("ClientName", null);
    gvBatchBilling.AutoFilterByColumn("TripCode", null);
    gvBatchBilling.ApplyFilter(
        ((clientNameFilter != "") ? "([ClientName] = '" + clientNameFilter + "') And" : "") +
        ((recordNameFilter != "") ? " ([TripCode] = '" + recordNameFilter + "') And" : "") +
        ((StartDateFromFilter != "") ? "([StartDate] >= #" + StartDateFromFilter + "#)  And" : "") +
        ((StartDateToFilter != "") ? "([StartDate] <= #" + StartDateToFilter + "#) And" : "") +
        ((ConfirmationDateFromFilter != "") ? "([ConfirmationDate] >= #" + ConfirmationDateFromFilter + "#)  And" : "") +
        ((ConfirmationDateToFilter != "") ? "([ConfirmationDate] <= #" + ConfirmationDateToFilter + "#)" : "")
    );
}
```

Comment: I does not want to apply all filter at the same time. Sometimes just I need one filter and sother times all of them :(